# Nuxt/Axios: baseURL with same origin, but different port possible?

Tags: express, axios, nuxt.js

Short:
How can I set a different port for axios request in `nuxt.config`, but with same origin domain?

Long:
On my production side I have an express server that delivers my frontend and backend over the same port (e.g. `http://192.168.2.22:8800`). Axios will make API requests on that same origin with same port. Works very well.

On my dev side I have an express server that delivers only my APIs and I also have the nuxt server, serving the frontend. Both running on different ports (e.g. `http://192.168.2.22:8800` for my backend and `http://192.168.2.22:3000` for my nuxt). So that I can also execute the API calls in my development environment, I set the `baseURL` in my `nuxt.config` to `http://localhost:8800`.

My problem here is, I can only test my dev environment if I'm on localhost. If I want to access via another pc, the api calls are also started on localhost, which is not reachable.

Is there a way to add a dynamic port to the baseURL?
My `nuxt.config` right now:

```js
axios: {
  baseURL: isDev ? 'http://localhost:8800/api/v1' : '/api/v1'
},
```

For a better overview.
This is what I want on my production (only express is running):

```
Frontend: http://192.168.2.22:8800
Backend: http://192.168.2.22:8800
```

This is what I want on my dev side (two servers are running - express and nuxt):

```
Frontend: http://192.168.2.22:3000
Backend: http://192.168.2.22:8800
```

Comment: Not sure that I quite understood the issue here. If you want to access to your server from anywhere in your local network, you could use `host: '0.0.0.0'` in your `nuxt.config.js` file, as showed here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-server

Comment: This way, you could reach your server with `localhost` or it's private local IP address (aka `192.168.1.XXX`). Otherwise, you configuration is great (`isDev`)!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Right now I can reach my dev environment, running on an raspberry pi over network from my pc. The problem is, when I access my frontend (for example `192.168.1.XXX:3000`), all axios api requests are still sent to `http://localhost:8800/api/v1`. Instead the api requests should sent to `http://192.168.1.XXX:8800/api/v1` (different port than the frontend).

Comment: Of course, if I run everything locally, I reach the frontend and the backend apis via localhost. Thats the way I'm developing right now. But I wish I could run my dev environment on a remote server (the raspberry pi).

Comment: Is your raspberry pi into your local network?

Comment: Yes, the raspberry pi is on my local network. I wish I could set everything dynamically. I don't want to set a fix hostname, or ip address. I wish I could do something like `baseURL: isDev ? ':8800/api/v1' : '/api/v1'`

Comment: Why not setting an environment variable with either your local IP or the RaspberryPi's one?

Comment: I still hope there is a solution that does not require a setup. However, that would be a workaround. I had not thought of that yet, thank you. :)

Comment: I mean, if your host is dynamic, you could maybe for an initial reach to define it but I'm not sure where to do this and you could actually be faster by passing inline variable directly to your run command. Like `HOST_MACHINE=192.168.2.13 yarn dev`

Comment: Hm... I think I will stick with the env variable. Its easier to set the variable as a one time setup on every device I want to develope and with 'localhost' as a fallback. On the production side everything works dynamic. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variable are still your best bet here indeed. It will help you configure each environment to your liking and will avoid a lot of mistakes too.

Here is an interesting article on the subject too: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config